# How to display image in kivymd without text?

Tags: python-3.x, image, kivy, kivymd

I am developing simple GUI program using kivymd.
I tried to display image with [Image List](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/image-list/?highlight=image) but ImageList occurs some problems so I need another widget that displays image.

I searched on kivymd but I found only Image List.
Is there some good widget that displays Image?

What I need:

1. I have to display image from url.
2. I don't want Image button. Just image.
3. I don't want any text on image.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/master/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.AsyncImage is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AsyncImage`. AsyncImage fetches images from url and show them when they are loaded. You can even add a loading screen of your own too. Also, I assume you want to show multiple images in a layout like in `ImageList`. So what you can do is create a `GridLayout` and inside that grid layout you can add multiple Async Images. You can check docs [here](https://kivy.org/doc/master/api-kivy.uix.image.html#kivy.uix.image.AsyncImage)

Comment: Thank you! This was what i wanted. I think I should researched more. Thanks again!